# Enable tooltip on just the selected elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have some complex form, and I want to enable tooltips for some groups of elements. Let's assume I have multiple `<li>` elements, each containing an `<input>` and a `<label>`):

```
<ul>
    <li><input ...> <label>...</label></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Then I'd like to add tooltips to each of the `<li>` elements so that when the user hovers anywhere inside the list item, the tooltip is visible:

```
$('li').each(function () {
    $(this).tooltip({ items: '*', content: 'test' })   
});
```

Of course, in my case I'm going to have a different `content` for each of the `<li>` elements. Whenever I call `tooltip()`, I'd like to add the tooltip for just the selected element. As my `<li>` elements do not have a `title` attribute, I have to pass some selector for `items`. I tried passing `*`, which kind of works, but has the side effect that each individual element gets its own tooltip, even though each of them has the same content. You can see it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/k2c3uego/4/

I know that for this example, I can just pass `li` as the selector, but this will not work when I have nested `<li>` elements or I can't find a simple selector for all the elements that I have already selected using jQuery in the first place.

Is there a way to call `tooltip()` in a way that adds the tooltip to just the selected elements (i.e. the elements contained in the selection on which `tooltop()` is called)?

Comment: I can just pass `this` for `items`!? http://jsfiddle.net/k2c3uego/5/ I'd be happy if someone could add an answer explaining this solution in more detail, maybe with a reference to the docs. Or is this an undocumented feature?

Comment: It is more of an accidental feature than an undocumented one. It works because `options.items` is only passed to the `find()` and `closest()` methods (for now), and both methods support taking an element as well as a selector. I cannot guarantee this situation will remain the same in the future, so I would recommend you do not rely on it too much.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thank you for the clarification. Is there another way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you only want to augment the top-level `<li>` elements (although that's not clear from the selector you're using). If that's the case, you can apply the widget to `document` and provide a selector that excludes nested `<li>` elements, e.g. `$(document).tooltip({ items: "li:not(li li)" })` with an appropriate `content` function.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi My fundamental question is not related to the example (where it would be easily achievable using one or another selector). My question is about how to add a tooltip to a [set of] selected elements, without knowing anything about them. Think of a library which to which an element is passed and which should add a tooltip to that element, regardless of the elements it contains.

Comment: Then the tooltip widget is not really suited to your purpose I'm afraid. Technically, you would have to find a way to express the set of matched elements as a selector. If that is not possible, I don't think the widget will work for you.

Comment: UI-wise, the tooltip widget does exactly what I beed. I think I'm going to wrap adding a tooltip to a specific element with a library function and when passing `this` stops working for some reason, I can still work around it by setting or using an `id` attribute on the element in question.